# Android and SQLite Queries

Tags: android, sqlite

Background: I'm taking an Android class right now and part of our final project requires retrieving data through an SQLite query. We're using the Chrome browser history to populate a RecyclerView. We're working off of an AVD and changed permissions on the history file (since, obviously, this isn't something that would normally be done) to make it readable. We have to use a SQLite query to get the data, though, and then do other stuff with it inside the app.

I've been digging around for the past couple of days and have found quite a few different examples for database connections in Android but they all seem to have a lot of unnecessary bloat that I don't need. I don't need to create or delete tables, I'm not adding or changing entries at all, I just need to query and get information back to play around with. I looked through the SQLiteDatabase documentation and the only thing that kind of looked like what I wanted would involve the beginTransaction() and endTransaction() methods. But I wasn't entirely sure.

I'm definitely not trying to like, covertly get others to do the work for me, but I wonder: is there a way I can query the database directly with a few lines in my code or from a relatively simple method? Or do I need to go through and implement something resembling the various database helper classes I've seen with all the extra functionality I don't need right now? Feel free to ask any follow up questions that may arise, if any. Thanks for any help you all can give!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to use one of the [SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#openDatabase(java.lang.String,%20android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory,%20int)) methods, with the OPEN_READONLY flag. Then, you can use methods like `query()` or `compileStatement()` on the returned SQLiteDatabase object.

Comment: Perfect! That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!